# How do I use the security features (encryption) of the Intel 660p SSD?

Tags: ssd, disk-encryption, self-encrypting-drive, tcg-storage-pyrite

I've placed an Intel 660p drive in a Lenovo T480s.
I can't figure out whether encryption is already in place, or if it's not, whether and how I can enable it.

- Lenovo's [FDE (full disk encryption) FAQ](https://support.lenovo.com/si/en/solutions/ht002240?tabName=Solutions) says:

`Any ThinkPad notebook that uses Serial ATA (SATA) hard drives can use an FDE drive; however, the FDE menu enable utility is only supported on some systems`

My T480s is not listed under supported systems but T400/410 etc are so I don't fully trust the page, it may be outdated.

- Various Intel 660p [product pages](https://www.bechtle.com/pl-en/shop/intel-660p-series-2-tb-m-2-nvme-ssd--4334854--p) as well as [reviews](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/intel-ssd-660p-qlc-nvme,5719.html) say that `The 660p features AES-256 encryption with Pyrite 1.0 and 2.0 support, which is a nice addition for the security conscious`, but this is not useful since Pyrite seems to be a specification which is not mentioned by the manufacturer (Lenovo), nor do I see such support with other laptops.
- [Another SE question](https://superuser.com/questions/403742/how-can-i-encrypt-an-intel-ssd) is useful in saying encryption would work out-of-the-box if the BIOS "ATA password" is set but I have no such password option, also the question refers to a different Intel SSD, the Intel 520. Also, the 660p is not a SATA drive - it is NVMe, but again, I don't know how this is relevant - do NVMe drives not require cooperation of the host system to implement encryption?
- The question has also been asked [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/204599/205215) but with no answer.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes you are right, but I tried to show more research. My conclusion so far (but without authoritative references)) is that the drive does _not_ provide encryption. The question you refer to mentions that in Microsoft land Bitlocker is used for this drive, which is software, lazy encryption method. I am using Linux and adding dm-crypt/LUKS partition-wise to my setup.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the drive does provide encryption. Each and every Intel SSD so far has offered it, including the G2 in my old laptop.

Comment: I got as far as reading this - https://www.winmagic.com/blog/opalite-pyrite-sed-specifications-simplified/ - including the linked document where it says _"Download full Pyrite SSC Specification FAQ"_. The Pyrite description is underwhelming - at best, Pyrite is a downscale/subset of Opal and Opalite. For example, the spec of my previous drive, a Samsung SSD 850 EVO, explicitly states _AES 256‐bit Full Disk Encryption_ and _TCG/Opal V2.0, Encrypted Drive (IEEE1667)_. The Intel doesn't say any of that.

Comment: True, but if you say that "the drive does *not* provide encryption" while the Intel specs claim hardware AES-256 encryption then something is going wrong.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes what you're saying is precisely my question. _Do_ the Intel specs claim hardware AES-256 encryption (that one can actually use)? I cannot find it. I.e. I can't find a way to use it, if it exists.