# How to access a hardware encrypted Intel 660p NVMe SSD when the system hardware it was encrypted on is no longer available?

Tags: ssd, disk-encryption, nvme, sedutil, tcg-storage-pyrite

I have an Intel 660p NVMe SSD whose spec lists:

- Hardware Encryption Yes
- Encryption Algorithm 256-bit AES

I used it as a replacement drive for Fujitsu Lifebook U748. That's the laptop I used to enable the hardware encryption on it using the facility available in BIOS. At some point I had to return the laptop and now I am left with the encrypted drive that I have no idea how to access.

The Fujitsu laptop's configuration lists various hard drive options including some that are "OPAL capable". I currently have access to Lenovo Thinkpad X280 where the spec lists "hard disk password" and which came with Hynix NVMe drive with "OPAL 2.0" on the sticker. I though I could use it to access my drive then.

I put the disk in and used `sedutil-cli` to query the drive but it didn't appear possible:

```
/dev/nvme0 No INTEL SSDPEKNW512GB
```

For completeness the output for the Hynix drive was:

```
/dev/nvme0 12 SKHynix_HFS256GD9TNG-L5B0B
```

I then tried with `hdparm` but got:

```
HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

and that's apparently because `hdparm` talks ATA which the drive being NVMe doesn't understand.

Finally, I put the drive into ASRock H470M-ITX/ac motherboard, as its explicitly listed on the QVL, but no joy, the system immediately froze, I wasn't even able to get into BIOS.

Is there anything I can do to access my drive?

Comment: Related – [How do I use the security features (encryption) of the Intel 660p SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/1428279/how-do-i-use-the-security-features-encryption-of-the-intel-660p-ssd)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can recover your data. From what I have read, on the disk there is a encryption key stored in the encrypted form. It can be decrypted using your BIOS password. Nothing more is disclosed nor the precise algorithm how that is actually done.

So I would be interested to know:

- When there is no BIOS password is the encryption key stored on the disk unencrypted and can you migrate such disk from one PC to another?
- What happens if you happen to modify BIOS password? Is your HDD then useless?
- When you take your disk into another computer with the same BIOS password will it work?

I am not aware Intel answering such questions nor disclosing any details.

So in theory if you were Intel and knew the password, you have a way to recover it, because on the disk it is encoded by your BIOS password. Unless they mix also password with some specific hardware information.

However there seems to be a way to erase the device and put it to factory state while losing data but at least having the disk working
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000057452/memory-and-storage.html

Comment: _> Nothing more is disclosed nor the precise algorithm how that is actually done._ This is not true. Intel 660p implements TCG Pyrite specification (at least this is what multiple sources say).

Answer (score 0):

Intel 660p supports [TCG Pyrite](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/resource/tcg-storage-security-subsystem-class-pyrite/), **not** [TCG Opal](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/resource/storage-work-group-storage-security-subsystem-class-opal/). `sedutil` might be useless for the former (and it obviously doesn't recognize *your* SSD).

You need to look for more specialized software. TrueNAS [claims](https://www.truenas.com/docs/core/coretutorials/storage/sed/#supported-specifications) Pyrite support.